# how to install mac 10.10 yosemite on pc?

Tags: mac, windows-8.1, osx-yosemite, toshiba-laptop

how to install mac 10.10 yosemite on pc , im now useing windows 8.1 and my laptop is toshiba satallite c 55 with : 
4 GB ram 
2.4 GHz processor
1 GB AMD graphic card  .

please help

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Duplicate: [Can you install Mac OS X on any PC?](https://superuser.com/q/344418)

Comment: There are ways to do it: see http://www.osx86project.org or http://www.hackintosh.com but your hardware does have to be compatible. They use much of the same nowadays, and many of the same actual suppliers for parts. As mentioned in the answers below, just realize the fact that Apple has stated it is against their license agreements.

Comment: Questions about running OS X on non-Apple hardware ("Hackintosh") are off-topic because of the questionable legality of doing so. See [Are "Hackintosh" questions allowed?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has implemented some functionalitys, that prohibit the Installation of OSX on non Apple Hardware.

Under some Special circumstances you are able to install OSX, if you have the same Hardware like an apple Machine and use a non apple bootloader called Hackintosh.

[here](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/04/the-best-hackintosh-laptops-of-2013-2014.html) is a List of know Laptops running with Hackintosh

But as far as i know it will not work on your Toshiba PC

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It goes against the License of OSX. Besides of that it's very difficult and you can't be sure that the final product is a working system.

There's a project called [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/)  where you can find guides to do it, however it's not guaranteed that you could have a working system because the very likely incompabilities among your hardware and the drivers on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You must not install Mac OS on non Apple-branded hardware. Additionally you cannot on most PCs.

This is because Apple uses in his operating system specialized code, which does only work on some Intel processors. As addition you can only use one specific WiFi, Bluetooth,... chip.

If you are planning to build your own pc, you could choose the right components to get the most things working, but there is no guarantee and, Apple says in its EULA (End User License Agreement), that you must not install apple os on an computer which is not apple-branded.